# Python for loop doesn't work right when it is inside of the command of a button

Tags: python-2.7, button, for-loop, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import sys

def openwindows():
    eText.set(open.show())
def loadfiles():
    filedirectory=eText.get()
    f=file(filedirectory)
    lines = f.readlines()
    length=len(lines)
    #vertex=[]
    #face=[]
    for x in range(0,length):
        print (x)




Root=Tk()
RTitle=Root.title("Assignment_2")
RWidth=Root.winfo_screenwidth()
RHeight=Root.winfo_screenheight()
Root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (RWidth/3,RHeight/3*2,RWidth/2-RWidth/6, RHeight/2-RHeight/3))

frame1 = Frame(Root)
frame1.pack()

Label(frame1, text="Filename: ").pack(side = LEFT)

eText = StringVar()
statusbar = Entry(frame1, state="readonly", textvariable=eText)
eText.set("pyramid.txt")
statusbar.pack(side = LEFT)

myfiletypes = [('text files', '*.txt'), ('All files', '*')]
open = tkFileDialog.Open(frame1, filetypes = myfiletypes)
Button(frame1, text="Browse", fg = "Blue", command=openwindows).pack(side = LEFT)
Button(frame1, text = "Load", fg = "red", command=loadfiles).pack(side=LEFT)

frame2 = Frame(Root)
frame2.pack()

Label(frame2, text="Rotation Axis: ").pack(side=LEFT)
r1 = IntVar()
r1.set(3)
Radiobutton(frame2, text="X", variable=r1, value=1).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(frame2, text="Y", variable=r1, value=2).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(frame2, text="Z", variable=r1, value=3).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(frame2, text="Line AB", variable=r1, value=4).pack(side=LEFT)

Label(frame2, text="A:").pack(side=LEFT)
pointA = Entry(frame2, width=10)
pointA.insert(0, "[0.0,0.0,0.0]")
pointA.pack(side=LEFT)

Label(frame2, text="B:").pack(side=LEFT)
pointB = Entry(frame2, width=10)
pointB.insert(0, "[1.0,1.0,1.0]")
pointB.pack(side=LEFT)

var1 = StringVar(Root)
var1.set("90")
Label(frame2, text="Degree:").pack(side=LEFT)
Spinbox(frame2, width=3, from_=0, to=350, increment=10, textvariable=var1).pack(side=LEFT)

var2 = StringVar(Root)
var2.set("5")
Label(frame2, text="Steps:").pack(side=LEFT)
Spinbox(frame2, width=3, from_= 1, to = 10, textvariable=var2).pack(side=LEFT)

Button(frame2, text = "Rotate", fg = "Blue").pack(side=LEFT)

frame3 = Frame(Root)
frame3.pack()

Label(frame3, text="Scale Ratio: ").pack(side=LEFT)
r2 = IntVar()
r2.set(1)
Radiobutton(frame3, text="All", variable=r2, value=1).pack(side=LEFT)
var3 = StringVar(Root)
var3.set("1")
Spinbox(frame3, width=4, from_= 0.25, to = 4, textvariable=var3, increment=0.25, format='%3.2f').pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(frame3, text="[Sx,Sy,Sz]", variable=r2, value=2).pack(side=LEFT)
scaleamount = Entry(frame3, width=10)
scaleamount.insert(0, "[1,1,1]")
scaleamount.pack(side=LEFT)
var4 = StringVar(Root)
var4.set("4")
Label(frame3, text="Steps:").pack(side=LEFT)
Spinbox(frame3, width=3, from_= 1, to = 10, textvariable=var4).pack(side=LEFT)

Button(frame3, text = "Scale", fg = "Blue").pack(side=LEFT)

separator = Frame(height=2, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
separator.pack(fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)

Canvas(Root, bg="Blue").pack(fill="both", expand=True)




mainloop()
```

when you click Load, its suppose to read the file and display this.

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
.....
```

whatever number of lined you have in the txt file. 
But the problem is that, it only displays this

```
0
```

which means the for loop only ran one time and thats it. 
if I close the program, then the rest of the numbers will show in the command prompt.
really weird... doesnt make sense.
the `loadfiles()` itself works perfectly fine. 
It just wont work with the button

Comment: What happens if you simply run that function? Print `lines` to see that it even reads the file.

Comment: @sashkello it works i tried.

Comment: Show the result of `print lines`.

Comment: @sashkello ['v 0 0 0\n', 'v .8 0 0\n', 'v 0 .8 0\n', 'v .8 .8 0\n', 'v 0.4 0.4 .7\n', 'f 4 2 1\n', 'f 3 4 1\n', 'f 2 5 1\n', 'f 5 3 1\n', 'f 2 4 5\n', 'f 3 5 4\n', 'w -1.0 -1.0 1\t1\n', 's 0.1 0.1 0.9 0.9\n', '\n']

Comment: @sashkello its like this function only runs 1 print statement, if I add the `print lines` in front of the `for loop`, only the `lines` will be printed, the `0` will be gone

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Copypasted your code, created a file and all works as it should.

Comment: Make sure that your text file is in the same folder as python file.

Comment: @sashkello weird... It works when i just simply open it as a py exe. It won't work in Wing IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with how the UI is processing.

Try replacing `print (x)` with

```
sys.stdout.write(str(x) + '\n')  # or "{}\n".format(x)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

If you search for tkinter and flush you will find plenty of conversations to read.

Comment: i found the problem, all of my code works fine if i just open it as a executable. if i try to run it in Wing IDE, it acts like this.

Comment: On my OSX box when I ran your code I saw the behavior you described. When I made the change I suggest above I see '0\n\1\n2\n0'.

Comment: `for x in range(0,length):
        sys.stdout.write(str(x) + '\n')  # or "{}\n".format(x)
        sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: Really you should be reading the data and putting it into a widget instead of fussing around with stdout. The bigger problem is you are going to block the UI until both the file I/O and the text output are completed. You really should have load be an idle processor or a thread.